# Python3 / pip3 module not found

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Whenever I try to run the following commands:

```
pip3 -v
pip3 install <module>
python3 -m pip install <module>
```

I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named random" with the traceback referencing a file in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/emailutils.py

Any ideas?

Comment: `random` module comes by default with python, no need to install it.

Comment: @techytushar that’s not the issue here, any time I try to install any other module, I get that error